# ClassNotFoundException com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

Tags: java, db2-luw

I have the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ImageDB
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My CLASSPATH has the db2jcc.jar:

```
.;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\java\db2java.zip;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\java\db2jcc.jar;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\java\sqlj.zip;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\BIN;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\java\common.jar
```

and related paths from my Path variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;
C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\BIN;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\FUNCTION;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\samples\repl;
E:\All_Junk\DB2\java
```

So my question is: why am I still getting the error?  Everything I've seen regarding this error has said that updating the CLASSPATH and/or Path variables will fix this, however Java is still unable to find the driver class.

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding the Driver to the Java project build path and see if it can find that one.

Comment: There is no project, just me and Notepad++.